Switch statement not working with my List objects
I am using multiple switch statements comparing strings to direct my program flow and when hard-coded to string values they work fine. I thought it would be convenient to store the strings in a List and then compare the list elements but the compiler is giving me an error. Code is below - the compiler error I get is

type or namespace lDetailing could not be found.

This is right after it is able to be referenced a few lines earlier.
private List<string> lDetailing = new List<string>()
      { "Engineering", "Internal", "Attorney", "Estimate" };

// get the fieldname from the recordset 
string sFieldName = dr.Field<string>(1);

//using the switch statement to find the list element that matches sFieldName

switch(sFieldName) 
{
  case lDetailing[0]:
           iFieldNum = 0;
           break;
  case lDetailing[1]:
            iFieldNum = 55;
            break;
  case lDetailing[2]:
            iFieldNum = 99;
            break;
}


As an aside, personally I wouldn't recommend using lists like this. Use constants.

You could use a Dictionary<string, int> for the lookup.
